# My terminal keeps printing "emergency" messages

Tags: terminal, printing

I keep getting these broadcast messages being printed to every terminal window, and it's driving me nuts. Does anybody have a clue as to how to turn them off?

```
Broadcast Message from _usbmuxd@10242-MacBook-Air.local                        
    (no tty) at 7:23 GMT...                                                

[03/12/2016 07:23:37] [Emergency] [update thread] uncaught exception: easyDNS 
Runtime Exception
```

Comment: you could make sure easyDNS is up to date correctly configured...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look in /var/log/system.log and see if you can get more information about the messages. Also look at the settings in /etc/syslog.conf

Answer (score 2):

Ok, this is what I did.

Like Brian Mc said, I checked my logs at /var/log/system.log. I found a little extra information. This is what the full line in the system log reads:

```
Mar 12 04:43:29 10242-MacBook-Air ddnsd[60]: [03/12/2016 04:43:29] [Emergency] [update thread] uncaught exception: easyDNS Runtime Exception
```

So I was like, huh! What's this "ddnsd" thing? So I looked through my processes for any process with a name like ddns.

I ran

```
ps aux|grep ddns
```

The command came back with:

```
abudu_h          1142   0.0  0.2  2538864   6496   ??  S     7:24AM   0:01.27 /Users/abudu_h/Library/Application Support/easyDNS/ddnsa.app/Contents/MacOS/ddnsa
```

I thought, I don't really need this program running, why not turn it off. So rather than delete it, what I did was make it non-executable.

```
cd /Users/abudu_h/Library/Application\ Support/easyDNS/
chmod -x ddnsa.app/
```

And hooray! The messages stopped.

Comment: It sounds like you were unaware of easyDNS being on your system. Did you just install and forget?

Comment: I remember installing it in the hopes I could connect MAMP to DNS services, but where to find it was the problem. It wasn't in the main Applications folder, and spotlight search wasn't helpful. I guess I never tried grepping through my entire hard-drive for it...